# i need help using the composite formatting in C#

Tags: c#, format, console.writeline

below is a method (function) of my program which is suppose to generate the specified month and year, i got that part right, but i need help formatting the days to be in the same column as the days of the week

```
static void GenMonth(int month, int year)
{
    int daycode, ndim;
    PrintHeader(month, year);
    ndim=GetNDIM(month,year);
    int day=1;
    daycode = GetDayCode(month, day, year);

    int a,i;
    for(a=1;a<=daycode;a++)
    {
        Console.Write("    ");
    }

    for (i = 1; i <= GetNDIM(month, year); i++)
    {
        Console.Write("{0,4}", i);
    }

    daycode = GetDayCode(month, day, year);
    if (daycode == 6)
    {
        Console.Write("\n");
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: how can i send a picture ?

Comment: just did, check it out and see if you can help me

Answer (score 0):

Print a new line every 7 numbers after the line, first line should be special case for different months

Comment: so should i do i a for loop nested in the last if statement ?

Comment: You could just use mod in your second for loop. E.g. `if (((i + daycode)%7) == 0) Console.Write("\n");`